# Is DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.DateTime equivalent to DateTime.UtcNow?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, type-conversion, datetimeoffset

I need to upgrade some piece of code from statically calling `DateTime.UtcNow` to calling a time provider service which returns, basically, `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`. To further convert this `DateTimeOffset` instance to `DateTime`, there is the `DateTime` property. Alternatively, it seems that there is an implicit conversion from `DateTimeOffset` to `DateTime`.

I'm a bit concerned that there might be some edge cases that I can't see right now where these two would not be equivalent. Are there?

Comment: "To further convert this DateTimeOffset instance to DateTime, there is the DateTime property" - there is also the `UtcDateTime` property, which seems more appropriate for your scenario

Answer (score 17):

If you look at the value of `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.DateTime.Kind` you will see the it is Unspecified. Unspecified kinds are treated as local times by the framework. The kind of `DateTime.UtcNow` is Utc, so there will be differences when timezone conversions are applied to and from the local timezone.

The work around is to use the `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.UtcDateTime` which has the Utc kind specified.

Comment: DateTimeOffset.UtcNow is not UTC? Why is the naming of property so confusing?

Answer (score 4):

Internally it looks like this:

```
  public static DateTimeOffset UtcNow {
        get { 
            return new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow);
        } 
  } 

  public DateTime DateTime { 
        get {
            return ClockDateTime;
        }
    } 
   private DateTime ClockDateTime { 
        get {
            return new DateTime((m_dateTime + Offset).Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified); 
        }
    }

  public DateTime UtcDateTime { 
        [Pure] 
        get {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<DateTime>().Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc); 
            return DateTime.SpecifyKind(m_dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        }
    }
```

So it looks like you could end up getting a DateTime that was based on UTC but then gets converted to `Unspecified`.

Comment: In which case calling `DateTime.SpecifyKind` on the result should be enough to make it entirely identical to `DateTime.UtcNow`, right?

Comment: Would seem correct, however wouldn't that make it the third DateTime object to be created? UTCNow, ClockDateTime and then finally the kind adjusted.  If the OP is happy to convert then yes that could be ok.  If it's some existing code that is relying on them being 100% equivalent then there may be problems.

Comment: Could I use `.UtcDateTime` instead of `.DateTime` property on the `DateTimeOffset` instance? Like so: `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.UtcDateTime`

Comment: `DateTime` is a value type, no object creation is involved (at least not in the way I think you mean) either way.

Comment: See edit and have a wander around http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetimeoffset.cs,04abe0cac293ebd0

Comment: @hvd totally true, I guess I automatically frown when I see lots of conversions of the same type back and forth being done :)

Answer (score 1):

From [the .NET reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetimeoffset.cs,04abe0cac293ebd0):

```
public static DateTimeOffset UtcNow {
    get {
        return new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow);
    }
}
```

So, yes, it looks like it's equivalent to `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: It seems to get further mangled a bit later on, so I think you're right they may have the same value but not sure about the `DateTimeKind` setting.